# How to design MongoDB collection relation correctly

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am trying to create a simple DB of Customers/Products/Orders to practice my skills with aggregate and so on. I need some help on how to design the relation between those collections correctly (that i'll really be able to store the details in the right way).

I go for the minimal build and information-->

Customer:

(1) customer_id ,
(2)orders (this will be an array with all the order_id's this customer did)

Product:

(1) product_id

Order:

(1) order_id , 
(2) products (this will be an array with all the products in this order) + I wonder how I add quantity for each product , 
(3) user_id (this will store the user_id did this order) or i don't even need this field??

I hope someone could tell me if this is a right thinking, because I come from SQL and this what I would do there I guess

// I'm not using embedded document because in case i'll want to change a specific field value it would change in all places